# dependency-check for application code

Tags: maven, security, owasp

I am looking for a solution to implement security-scanning of the application code-base at the time of a build. The idea is to capture a list of security vulnerabilities early in the software development life cycle.

I have a simple java project which uses a maven build. The java project specifies a number of .jar dependencies and comes up with a .war file as a build output.

I came across (and was able to configure) the **dependency-check** maven plugin (http://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/index.html). However, though it scans the dependency jars and comes up with a vulnerability report, it doesn't seem to scan the final artifact - which in my case is the .war file.

How do I ensure that the .war is scanned as well? Is the **dependency-check** plugin the right tool for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**dependency-check** isn't the right tool for checking your own code. It uses a list of known vulnerability reports to determine if any of your dependancies have known flaws. It does not do an active scan of the code. see [Plugin wiki](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check)

For checking your own code, HP's Fortify is a decent commercial solution, but if you are working in more of a DIY software setting, I would recommend Sonar. There are certainly many *static code analysis* tools out there. All have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks @micker. However judging from some comments on the Internet (http://meera-subbarao.blogspot.co.nz/2012/11/sonar-owasp-plug-in.html), the sonar option doesn't seem robust enough. Are there other open-source options you could suggest?

Comment: Sonar (with FindBugs) is the most robust open source solution that I know of. Static code analysis is a hard problem which is why there is so much research going into it. False-positives are a really big problem among these tools which is why they require lots of tuning and manual review. You may want to consider a commercial option if Sonar isn't sufficient, but they will have problems as well.